# How to turn off "Failed to open the file" logs for invariant resources?

Tags: logging, resource-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resource files creates unnecessary ULS log entries](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21709/resource-files-creates-unnecessary-uls-log-entries)

With invariant resources in the SharePoint solutions, we have a lot of spammed logs, such as

```
Failed to open the file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources\ProjectResources.en-US.resx'. 
#20015: Cannot open "": no such file or folder. 
(#2: Cannot open "": no such file or folder.) 
Failed to read resource file "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\1
```

[Our college](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21709/resource-files-creates-unnecessary-uls-log-entries) didn't find any solution to tell SharePoint what resource are correct and where isn't any errors. So, I want to turn off exactly this logs. Where are a lot off categories in diagnostics logs. How can i determine what category this log belong to?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could make a copy of the ProjectResources.resx, then rename it as ProjectResources.en-US.resx.

Comment: Yes, I can. But it's very uncomfortable to copy and rename file after any changes. Wow, I can make it in the feature receiver! It will be helpfull in most cases, but make copy for each locale isn't usefull. Now feature receiver is solving my case. Thx :)